# Does LZSS data compression support on-the-fly decompression at the embedded side?

Tags: memory-management, embedded, compression

Scenario: Data (fpga images- .bin files) being compressed at the host, sent to the fpga(embedded side) in packets of 62 bytes and decompressed there. My target is to minimize the memory usage and cpu cost at the embedded side.

Question- Using LZSS data compression technique with large block size: on the embedded side- I assume the block size is a chunk of data before compression. If we pick a 2048 block size, and that compresses to, say, 1000 bytes....do we need to have all 1000 bytes on the embedded side at the same time to be able to decompress it? Or can we take that 1000 bytes and decompress it on-the-fly as we stream 62 bytes at a time?

Comment: Have you found a solution for that , have you implemented the LZSS algorithm in what language ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Wikipedia LZ77 and LZ78](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78):

> To spot matches, the encoder must keep track of some amount of the
>   most recent data, such as the last 2 kB, 4 kB, or 32 kB. The structure
>   in which this data is held is called a sliding window, which is why
>   LZ77 is sometimes called sliding window compression. The encoder needs
>   to keep this data to look for matches, and the decoder needs to keep
>   this data to interpret the matches the encoder refers to. The larger
>   the sliding window is, the longer back the encoder may search for
>   creating references.

So you need to configure the size of the sliding window appropriately during compression to be <= 62 bytes. Otherwise, you'll need to keep your older compressed packets in case they are referred to, this will make the implementation complex.

In my opinion, it's easier to just compress 62 bytes at a time. This will lead to lower compression efficiency but a faster implementation.

Comment: i have the same issue but i'm using CAN Bus (the frame can contain data limited to 8 bytes) to send my compressed data ... in the host (MCP5748: wich got only 768 kb of RAM) so when the data is in the host how to do to decompress it , it would take a long time to decompress each 8 bytes , maybe i must combine the bytes to form a data buffer before flashing it !!!